# SQL Server : exclude all results when a case exists

Tags: sql-server, database

I need a query that will exclude all results when a case exists. I have a Market Basket which can contain multiple Items, but now I just want to get all the Baskets which didn't buy a Keyboard (so only BThird should appear).

Table `Basket`

| ID_Basket |
| --- |
| BFirst |
| BSecond |
| BThird |

Table `Items`:

| ID_Items | FK_ID_Basket | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BFirst | Keyboard |
| 2 | BSecond | Keyboard |
| 3 | BSecond | Cup |
| 4 | BSecond | Smartphone |
| 5 | BThird | Smartphone |

If I just do a regular query with `Where Not like 'Keyboard'`, I also get the cup and smartphone from BSecond which I don't want.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with a [common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and a `LEFT JOIN` where the right side of the join is `NULL`.

```
;with CTE
AS (
    select distinct FK_ID_Basket
    from [Items]
    where [name]='Keyboard'
    )
select *
from basket b
left join CTE c
    on b.ID_basket = c.FK_ID_Basket
where c.FK_ID_Basket IS NULL
```

Comment: Perfect I just had to change where c.FK_ID_Basket IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to know where something does not exist, so use `not exists`

```
select * 
from Basket b
where not exists (select * from Items i where i.fk_id_basket=b.id_Basket and i.name='keyboard')
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a subquery:

```
 select distinct FK_ID_Basket
        from Basket b
        where b.name <> 'Keyboard' 
        and b.FK_ID_Basket not in (SELECT FK_ID_Basket from Basket where name = 'Keyboard')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with data as (
    select *,
        count(case when lower(Name) like '%keyboard%' then 1 end)
            over (partition by FK_ID_Basket) as kb_cnt
    from T
)
select FK_ID_Basket /* , ... */ from data where kb_cnt = 0;
```

As I originally wrote this I presumed that other columns would come along in the output. If that's not the case then you can use `having` to filter the groups and return only the basket id.

```
select FK_ID_Basket from T
group by FK_ID_Basket
having count(case when lower(Name) like '%keyboard%' then 1 end) = 0
```